# Chrome discards changes of textarea when new textbox is added to a form and "back" to the page

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome

Please look at this HTML:

```
<script>
function insert() { 
   document.getElementById("add").innerHTML="<input name=a>";
}
</script>
<button onclick="insert()">Insert new textbox</button>
<form>
  <div id="add"></div>
  <textarea name=b>a</textarea>
  <a href="other.html">Go</a>
  <!-- The content of other.html does not matter -->
</form>
```

And open this page in Chrome(Win7 64bit, 24.0.1312.52 m)

- Add some text into textarea like "b" (the value of textarea will be "ab")
- Select "Go" link, other.html is shown
- "Back" to this page, then the value of textarea remains "ab"
- Press "Insert new textbox"
- Select "Go" link
- "Back" again, then the value of textarea gets back to "a"!

Not only this procedure, once "Insert new textbox" is pressed, Chrome no longer remember the changes of the form when I "back"s to this page.

This does not occur in other browsers(They could keep values "ab" to the end):

- Opera 11.11
- Firefox 12.0
- IE 9.0.12

Is this a bug of Chrome? Or do I have something to avoid this?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Lsnvp/

Comment: I don't think this is a bug, since no one says the value should be kept when `[back]` is pressed.

Comment: And also the value `ab` is kept when I press the back button. Look at the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Lsnvp/). (Using Chrome 24)

Comment: Thanks Derek. But when I changed your Javascript code to $("div#add").append("<input name=a>"); // append name attribute , the value ab is not kept.

Comment: Hm, interesting. It shouldn't be happening because [`name` is just `id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-name-A) and should not behave differently.

Comment: Working for me using: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Lsnvp/show/ Moreover, I don't believe remembering the values after page was unloaded is part of spec. It is just something extra that browsers provide.

Comment: I agree with sv_in. And if you really want the browser to remember the values for you, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) or [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie) to store them.

Comment: Thanks Derek and sv_in, I have changed my applicaton; I put a new textarea to the next page, that has the changed content of the first page so that users need not go "back".